# specjour error trace

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, stack-trace, specjour

I have been battling this error with specjour for the past couple hours, and finally I am coming to everyone here.

I am trying to run the gem specjour on a ubuntu computer and keep getting this error

```
$ specjour
Looking for managers...
No listeners found on this machine, starting one...
/home/austin/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p302/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:29:in `gem_original_require': no such file to load -- rspec/core (LoadError)
    from /home/austin/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p302/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:29:in `require'
    from /home/austin/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p302@project/gems/specjour-0.4.1/lib/specjour/rspec.rb:3
    from /home/austin/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p302/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:29:in `gem_original_require'
    from /home/austin/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p302/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:29:in `require'
    from /home/austin/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p302@project/gems/specjour-0.4.1/lib/specjour/manager.rb:4
    from /home/austin/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p302@project/gems/specjour-0.4.1/lib/specjour/dispatcher.rb:94:in `fork_local_manager'
    from /home/austin/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p302@project/gems/specjour-0.4.1/lib/specjour/dispatcher.rb:106:in `gather_managers'
    from /home/austin/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p302@project/gems/specjour-0.4.1/lib/specjour/dispatcher.rb:23:in `start'
    from /home/austin/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p302@project/gems/specjour-0.4.1/lib/specjour/cli.rb:49:in `dispatch'
    from /home/austin/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p302@project/gems/thor-0.14.6/lib/thor/task.rb:22:in `send'
    from /home/austin/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p302@project/gems/thor-0.14.6/lib/thor/task.rb:22:in `run'
    from /home/austin/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p302@project/gems/thor-0.14.6/lib/thor/invocation.rb:118:in `invoke_task'
    from /home/austin/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p302@project/gems/thor-0.14.6/lib/thor.rb:263:in `dispatch'
    from /home/austin/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p302@project/gems/thor-0.14.6/lib/thor/base.rb:389:in `start'
    from /home/austin/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p302@project/gems/specjour-0.4.1/lib/specjour/cli.rb:18:in `start'
    from /home/austin/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p302@project/gems/specjour-0.4.1/bin/specjour:5
    from /home/austin/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p302@project/bin/specjour:19:in `load'
    from /home/austin/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p302@project/bin/specjour:19
```

If any one has anyidea how I can manage it I would be extremely grateful.

```
$ gem list --local

*** LOCAL GEMS ***

abstract (1.0.0)
actionmailer (2.3.8)
actionpack (2.3.8)
activerecord (2.3.8)
activeresource (2.3.8)
activesupport (2.3.8)
block_helpers (0.3.2)
braintree (2.10.1)
builder (3.0.0)
bundler (1.0.15)
capybara (0.3.9)
carrierwave (0.4.10)
childprocess (0.1.4)
chronic (0.2.3)
columnize (0.3.4)
configuration (1.3.1)
culerity (0.2.15)
daemons (1.1.4)
database_cleaner (0.5.0)
decent_exposure (1.0.0.rc1)
devise (1.0.7)
dnssd (1.3.4)
engineyard (1.2.4)
erubis (2.6.5)
escape (0.0.4)
eventmachine (0.12.10)
factory_girl (1.2.4)
faker (0.3.1)
fastercsv (1.5.4)
ffi (0.6.3)
geokit (1.5.0)
haml (3.0.18)
highline (1.5.2)
hoe (2.10.0)
hoptoad_notifier (2.4.2)
json (1.5.3)
json_pure (1.5.3)
launchy (0.3.5)
linecache (0.46)
mail_safe (0.3.1)
mime-types (1.16)
mini_magick (3.3)
mocha (0.9.8)
mysql (2.8.1)
newrelic_rpm (3.1.0)
nokogiri (1.5.0)
rack (1.1.2)
rack-bug (0.3.0)
rack-test (0.6.0)
rails (2.3.8)
rake (0.9.2, 0.8.7)
rbx-require-relative (0.0.5)
redis (2.2.1)
redis-namespace (0.7.0)
resque (1.9.7)
resque-scheduler (1.9.7)
rest-client (1.6.3)
rspec (1.3.0)
rspec-rails (1.3.2)
ruby-debug (0.10.4)
ruby-debug-base (0.10.4)
ruby-termios (0.9.6)
rubyzip (0.9.4)
rufus-scheduler (2.0.10)
searchlogic (2.4.19)
selenium-webdriver (0.1.1)
shoulda (2.10.3)
sinatra (1.2.6)
slug (0.5.5)
specjour (0.4.1)
ssl_requirement (0.1.0)
subexec (0.1.0)
system_timer (1.0)
thin (1.2.7)
thor (0.14.6)
tilt (1.3.2)
timecop (0.3.4)
tzinfo (0.3.29)
unicorn (1.1.3)
vegas (0.1.8)
warden (0.10.7)
watchr (0.7)
will_paginate (2.3.14)
```

As you can see rspec is installed and running just the spec command works just fine.

Here is the cat ./Gemfile

```
$ cat ./Gemfile bundle show
source :gemcutter

gem 'aasm', :git => 'git://github.com/rubyist/aasm.git', :branch => 'master'
gem 'block_helpers', '0.3.2'
gem 'braintree'
gem 'carrierwave'
gem 'chronic', '0.2.3'
gem 'decent_exposure', '1.0.0.rc1'
gem 'devise', '1.0.7'
gem 'erubis', '2.6.5'
gem 'geokit', '1.5.0'
gem 'haml', '3.0.18'
gem 'hoptoad_notifier', '2.4.2'
gem 'k_means', '0.0.6', :git => 'git://github.com/leosoto/K-Means.git', :branch => 'master'
gem 'newrelic_rpm'
gem 'mini_magick'
gem 'mysql'
gem 'rails', '2.3.8'
gem 'resque', '1.9.7'
gem 'resque-scheduler', '1.9.7'
gem 'searchlogic', '2.4.19'
gem 'seed-fu', '1.2.3', :git => 'git://github.com/supaspoida/seed-fu.git', :branch => 'master'
gem 'ssl_requirement', '0.1.0'
gem 'system_timer', '1.0'
gem 'slug', "0.5.5"
gem 'unicorn', '1.1.3' 
gem 'will_paginate', '2.3.14'
gem 'fastercsv'

group :development do
  gem 'engineyard', '1.2.4'
  gem 'rack-bug'
end

group :staging, :development do
  gem 'mail_safe', '~> 0.3.1'
end

group :test, :development, :staging, :data_correction do
  gem 'factory_girl', '1.2.4'
  gem 'faker', '0.3.1'
  gem 'ruby-debug'
  gem 'thin', '1.2.7'
end

group :test do
  gem 'capybara', '0.3.9'
  gem 'database_cleaner', '0.5.0'
  gem 'email_spec', :git => 'git://github.com/bmabey/email-spec.git', :branch => '0.6-rails2-compat'
  gem 'launchy', '0.3.5'
  gem 'mocha', '0.9.8'
  gem 'rspec', '1.3.0'
  gem 'rspec-rails', '1.3.2'
  gem 'selenium-webdriver', '0.1.1'
  gem 'shoulda', '2.10.3'
  gem 'specjour', '0.4.1'
  gem 'timecop', '0.3.4'
  gem 'watchr'
end
cat: bundle: No such file or directory
cat: show: No such file or directory
```

And here is the `bundle show`

```
$ bundle show
Gems included by the bundle:
  * aasm (2.2.0 2feec2a)
  * abstract (1.0.0)
  * actionmailer (2.3.8)
  * actionpack (2.3.8)
  * activerecord (2.3.8)
  * activeresource (2.3.8)
  * activesupport (2.3.8)
  * block_helpers (0.3.2)
  * braintree (2.10.1)
  * builder (3.0.0)
  * bundler (1.0.15)
  * capybara (0.3.9)
  * carrierwave (0.4.10)
  * childprocess (0.1.4)
  * chronic (0.2.3)
  * columnize (0.3.4)
  * configuration (1.3.1)
  * culerity (0.2.15)
  * daemons (1.1.4)
  * database_cleaner (0.5.0)
  * decent_exposure (1.0.0.rc1)
  * devise (1.0.7)
  * dnssd (1.3.4)
  * email_spec (0.6.6 6579c88)
  * engineyard (1.2.4)
  * erubis (2.6.5)
  * escape (0.0.4)
  * eventmachine (0.12.10)
  * factory_girl (1.2.4)
  * faker (0.3.1)
  * fastercsv (1.5.4)
  * ffi (0.6.3)
  * geokit (1.5.0)
  * haml (3.0.18)
  * highline (1.5.2)
  * hoe (2.10.0)
  * hoptoad_notifier (2.4.2)
  * json (1.5.3)
  * json_pure (1.5.3)
  * k_means (0.0.6 55baa81)
  * launchy (0.3.5)
  * linecache (0.46)
  * mail_safe (0.3.1)
  * mime-types (1.16)
  * mini_magick (3.3)
  * mocha (0.9.8)
  * mysql (2.8.1)
  * newrelic_rpm (3.1.0)
  * nokogiri (1.5.0)
  * rack (1.1.2)
  * rack-bug (0.3.0)
  * rack-test (0.6.0)
  * rails (2.3.8)
  * rake (0.9.2)
  * rbx-require-relative (0.0.5)
  * redis (2.2.1)
  * redis-namespace (0.7.0)
  * resque (1.9.7)
  * resque-scheduler (1.9.7)
  * rest-client (1.6.3)
  * rspec (1.3.0)
  * rspec-rails (1.3.2)
  * ruby-debug (0.10.4)
  * ruby-debug-base (0.10.4)
  * ruby-termios (0.9.6)
  * rubyzip (0.9.4)
  * rufus-scheduler (2.0.10)
  * searchlogic (2.4.19)
  * seed-fu (1.2.3 8673272)
  * selenium-webdriver (0.1.1)
  * shoulda (2.10.3)
  * sinatra (1.2.6)
  * slug (0.5.5)
  * specjour (0.4.1)
  * ssl_requirement (0.1.0)
  * subexec (0.1.0)
  * system_timer (1.0)
  * thin (1.2.7)
  * thor (0.14.6)
  * tilt (1.3.2)
  * timecop (0.3.4)
  * tzinfo (0.3.29)
  * unicorn (1.1.3)
  * vegas (0.1.8)
  * warden (0.10.7)
  * watchr (0.7)
  * will_paginate (2.3.14)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the error is about unsatisfied dependience, can you try to install **rspec** gem

Comment: rspec is installed check out the question I added `$gem list --local`

Comment: is this rspec version compatible with your version specjour? Do you use Bundler to manage it?

Comment: is the problem not on your mac?

Comment: the problem is on a ubuntu box

Comment: try to recreate RVM gemset, then delete Bundle.lock on server and bundle install

Comment: Do you the same environment? is the bug fixed?

Comment: same environment.rb same ruby/rails versions all rvm controlled still not fixed

Comment: Can you copy-paste outputs: **cat ./Gemfile** **bundle show**

Comment: @mikhailov let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/1663/discussion-between-austinbv-and-mikhailov)

Comment: The answer I found was a version mismatch